# how to config web.config for debug/release bundle minification?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

i´m trying to configure bundle minifications on/off depending on if is a `release` or `debug` configuration.

After a while, when the build is pointed to `release` i still got unminified field.

I just added

```
        #if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        #else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        #endif
```

But I would like if is possible has this configuration in the Web.Debug.config/Web.Release.config respectively instead of use a compiler directive.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to optimize or not is not *directly* dependent on the build configuration but rather on the following flag:

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

And the above is read from your `Web.Config`:

```
<compilation debug="true" />
```

So, if your solution is configured to remove this `debug` flag as part of your `RELEASE` build transformation then you'll have optimization turned on without the need to explicitly call `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations`.

So, make sure your `RELEASE` build transformation is indeed removing the `debug` flag.

More on [Bundling & Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)